# How to add fields which are not available in database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am not able to add field which is not available in my database

I have tried adding

```
$this->crud->addFields([
    [
        'name'        => 'coupon_type',
        'label' => 'Coupon For',
        'type'        => 'select_from_array',
        'options'     => [ 
            // Options
        ],
        'allows_null' => true,
        'default' => 1,
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'coupon_type'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

I want to add fields in my create page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining accessors for your "virtual" attributes

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['admin'] == 'yes';
}
```

and defining the `appends` on your model

`protected $appends = ['is_admin'];`

Find everything in the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json